# Bootstrap: How to collapse 2 nav OR change the content of one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

You're my last hope <3

I'm trying to do 2 solutions but none of them is working. (And sorry for my bad english)

Here is the **Bootply** : http://www.bootply.com/2aDcL7pYQZ

As you can see, I've 2 navbars. I'm trying to do 2 solutions when you resize the window for "Smartphone" *(because the website will be duplicate with those 2 effects)*.

**First solution :**

[image: First Solution]

Replace the links "Faire un don" and "Recrutement" with FontAwesome glyphs next to Youtube... But it doesn't work at all, I tried all positions (absolute, ...) and to change the display (inline, inline-block) none of them works. And to be honest, I don't even know how to change it :(

**Second solution :**

[image: Second Solution]

Move those two links in the other navbar.
Here is a **Bootply** that works great : http://www.bootply.com/106921 *(I found it on StackOverflow)*
I tried it and many others and it still not works... It just deletes my links.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Please also mention what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I added images ;) (I did it very fastly :s)

Comment: So what is not working ?  
Do you want to hide or display elements based on width of device ? ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to use the utilities, for example add this to your mini menu to hide them on small screens:

`.hidden-xs`

For the larger menu use

`.visible-xs-block` or `.visible-xs-inline` depending on how your menu is set up

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Oh my god... That was easy for the 1st solution! It works very great! Thank you. Now i just have to find how to do the second solution :p

Comment: This is a working example for both solution! Thank you again ;) http://www.bootply.com/q9SLbiFqdX

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to hide or display elements based on width you can use bootstrap classes

```
visible-xs : visible only in mobile (hidden for all other sizes)
hidden-xs : hide only in mobile (visible for all other sizes)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm french too. But I'm on StackOverFlow to improve my English, so I will try to help you in English! (Surely lot of mistakes).

I think that you can use this solution :

Firstly :

```
<div class="littleMenu">
    <a href="#" class="icon-button youtube">
        <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>
           <span></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="icon-button youtube">
        <i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i>
           <span></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Secondly:

Hide icons buttons in the css naturally:

```
.littleMenu{
    display:none;
}
```

Thirdly :

Use javascript/jquery functions to hide/show them when the document is ready or at resizing like I do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    if ($(window).width() <= 800){  
        $('#menu').hide();
        $('#menu2').show();       
    }   
    else if ($(window).width() > 800){  
        $('#menu').show();
        $('#menu2').hide();
        $('#menu3').hide();
    }     
});
```

and

```
//----------- Resize ------------//
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 800){  
        $('#menu').hide();
        $('#menu2').show();
    }
    if ($(window).width() > 800){   
        $('#menu').show();
        $('#menu2').hide();
        $('#menu3').hide();
    }

});
```

Use the same system for the second solution.

At hope that it will help you.

Keep me informed.

Comment: I tried this but I don't know why it doesn't work properly... The Euro icon is moved :p http://www.bootply.com/7A3eNat8ij
Did i do something wrong?

Comment: Lahar and David's solutions is better. Try to use them.